# When scrolling to top of div hide another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is what I have so far:

```
    $("#main").each(function() {this.scrollTop = this.scrollHeight;

        if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
         {
            $('#navigation').addClass("nav-hide");
         }
        else
         {
            $('#navigation').addClass("nav-normal");
         }
     });
```

So basically, I am trying to figure out when you scroll to the top of a div it will hide the navigation bar. So you could read the div without the navigation bar over it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qb15p5g7/3/

Comment: note you are using: $("#main").each(function().. however this will only ever be one instance since you are targetting an Id (assuming that you only have a single element on that page with that id). You should only use .each() for elements that have more than one instance (for example $(".pageSection").each(function()...) and I agree with @Maxwell Lasky in his approach of using .scroll()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jquery's window scroll function and not each function unless you are going to have more than one section that you need to hide the navigation on there is no reason to use each and I'm assuming that you don't because you are using an id for #main and Id's are supposed to be unique.  Also you don't need to add more than one class you can just add the class and remove the class.  So if im correct in assuming that you don't have more than one section that you need to hide the nav in multiple instances on your page then your code should look something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#main').offset().top) {
    $('#navigation').addClass("nav-hide");
  }else {
    $('#navigation').removeClass("nav-hide");
  }
});
```

And you will just add the nav-hide class and then remove it when scrolling back up.

Here is a fiddle of this working [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/svtmrjsy/)

I assume this is what you are looking for if not let me know so I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(window).scroll()` method executes on scroll change of the window. You can use it to hide your `#navigation` id selector

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#navigation').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#navigation').fadeOut();
    }
});​
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o6e821tc/)

See the jQuery documentation for .scroll() [here](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Comment: I'm trying to get the number value to be the `.height()` of the window document, so when scrolled the section below the header will hide the navigation. I'm pretty new to jQuery sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function scrollpos() {
    if (window.scrollY<document.getElementById('header').clientHeight)    {
    document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = 'block';
} else {
    document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

```css
#navigation {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #586e75;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
        transition: transform 200ms ease;
    }
    
    header,
    section {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        position: static;
    }
    
    header {
        background: #4f4244;
    }
    
    section {
        background: #222222;
    }
    
    .nav-normal {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
    
    .nav-hide {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
```

```html
<body onscroll="scrollpos()">
        <div id="navigation"></div>
        <header id="header"></header>
        <section id="main"></section>
</body>
```

do u need something like this?@Steboney

Comment: No this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: do u want to hide the navigation bar when the scroll bar comes below the header?

Comment: I have edited the fiddle please check it and let me know.